# Best route based on HERE Studio data

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

what I'm trying to do it's quite simple, but I can't figure out how to do it with HERE.
I have multiple polygons with a property [0...10] that defines the air quality of an area.

What I need to do is to create an optimal route for pedestrians in order move from A to B passing through areas with best air quality.

So my goal is that the route:

- Should categorically avoid areas with air_quality < 2 (that's simple I think with the "avoid" query parameter in the API)
- To pass through areas with the best air quality as possible. That's what I can't figure how to do.

Little suggestion. I think that the goal to "pass through areas with the best air quality as possible" is conceptually similar to a bike that has to be routed without changing too much its altitude. But again, I don't know how to do that with HERE APIs!

Answer (score 0):

The routing provides API to avoid certain zones when selecting route. However,  the other way of selecting like preferred areas is not available.

Currently, three-zone categories are supported, namely vignette, congestionPricing and environmental (see API Reference for more details). vignette roads are found in some European countries. The system works based on payment for a fixed time period (for example, one year). A traveler may want to avoid those roads to save the annual cost for occasional crossings. congestionPricing zones are another category of routing zones that consists of roads usually in the city centers, airports, bridges, or other busy areas. It is used to mitigate traffic congestion by charging a higher price in rush hours. environmental zones, on the other hand, are designed to improve air quality in urban areas by excluding vehicles under certain pollution standards from entering them.

For each category, there are multiple instances. For example, most cities in Germany have their own environmental zones. Each zone instance has its unique ID to identify it respectively.

Information about the various routing zones originates from the respective catalogs of platform.here.com. For example https://platform.here.com/data/hrn:here:data::olp-here:rib-2/environmental-zones/overview for Environmental Zones. If you do not have access to the platform catalogs then you can use the routing response to get this information.

Detail information provided in the below documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/avoid-zones.html